# select different value depend on the other columns' tag/value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has 4 columns (`customer, gender, division, product`)
gender has unique value linking to each customer: `male`, `female` or `null`.

The division has unique value linking to each product: men or women

for a male customer may buy the women products, vice versa, for female bought men's product

I want to create a table, only select the records/rows having the men's product to male and only women product for female (if the gender is null select women products records)
is there any simple way to do that

I did a complicated process. first, use customer info to separate male and other customers, (created 2 tables, cust_male, and cust_other)

then use join if the customer in the cust_male table, return the men division products rows (where division='men'); if the customer in the  cust_other table, return women division products rows (where division='women') then 'union all' two parts.

Hope I could have a much simple way or code to solve this.

we can use the code to create the tep table

```
create table tep (id, gender, division, product) as
(
  select 1, ‘male’, ‘men’, ‘aaa’ from dual
  union all select 2, ‘female’, ‘women’, ’bbb’ from dual
  union all select 2, ‘female’, ‘men’, ‘ccc’ from dual
  union all select 1, ‘male’, ‘women’, ‘ddd’ from dual
  union all select 3, ‘female’, ‘women’, ’ddd’ from dual
  union all select 4, ‘null’, ‘women’, ’eee’ from dual
 union all select 4, ‘null, ‘men, ’ccc’ from dual
);
```

my method was

```
create table cust_male as
select id from tep where gender='male';

create table cust_other as
select id from tep where (gender ='female') or (gender='null');

select * from tep t
inner join cust_male m
on m.id=t.id
where division ='men'

union all

select * from tep t
inner join cust_other f
on f.id=t.id
where division ='women'
```

hope I do not need to create those two more tables and having simple we to realize choosing only men's division product rows for male, and choose women's division product rows for female or null customers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to create a table, only select the records/rows having the men's product to male and only women product for female (if the gender is null select women products records) is there any simple way to do that

You want to filter the data, so this sounds like a `where` clause:

```
select tep.*
from tep
where (gender = 'male' and division = 'men') or
      ((gender = 'female' or gender is null) and division = 'women')
```